# Parse the output of a command only when it's an error, and only with native batch commands

Tags: windows, redirect, batch-file, command-line

I'm writing a batch file that is calling a command, and I want to handle any errors that might result. I have as a requirement that I use only the native CLI commands; in other words, I know I could easily accomplish this if I were using PowerShell or whatever, but I'm not.

What I want is if an error occurs, check the output, and if the error is expected, continue processing, otherwise abort. However, I'm having trouble parsing the output in a useful way.

This seems to be as close as I can get:

```
command | (find /i "valid" >NUL && goto :okay || goto :stop)
```

Here, I'm piping the output of the command to `find`. The trouble is, this occurs regardless of the exit status of the command - it sends both the success and failure messages. One option would be:

```
command 1>NUL 2>(find /i "valid" >NUL && goto :okay || goto :stop)
```

However, this doesn't work, because it's attempting to redirect to a file; the `find` command doesn't receive the input.

(For testing purposes, `command` is a cmd file that echos a message, and `exit /b 1` for an error)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Based on what you list as known

- On success, the errorlevel = 0
- On error, the errorlevel = 1.
- On error, an error message is written to the STDERR (2) stream.
- On an "EXPECTED" error, the word "valid" is output.

Try this:

```
command 2>&1 1>nul | ( find /i "valid" >nul && goto okay || goto stop )
```

***NOTE: the order in which the output re-directions take place is important!***

CMD parses the redirects from left to right. This is directing STDERR to STDOUT and then directing STDOUT to NUL. Think of them like pointers.  STDERR is getting the address of STDOUT before we set STDOUT to NULL.

#### Update

- On error, an error message is written to the STDOUT (1) stream.

Option A:

```
call command > "%Temp%\out.txt" && goto okay || ( find /i "valid" "%Temp%\out.txt" >nul && goto okay || goto stop )
```

Option B:

```
( call command && echo valid ) | find /i "valid" >nul && goto okay || goto stop
```

Comment: Well, based on your recommendation, I went back and looked at what was getting written out.  It appears that any messages generated are written to the stdout, including the error message.  So, maybe I should just deal with it that way?

Comment: @end-user  Will your real command be writing to STDERR?  You mentioned that you were just using a cmd file for testing.  To echo to the STDERR do this `echo string 1>&2`

Comment: No, I don't think so.  I tested generating an error, and it wrote to STDOUT with ERRORLEVEL > 0.  I only need to `find` if there's an error.  However, I don't know how to send the output to find once the command exits.

Comment: Yep - that was the logic I was missing.  It's not really pretty; Option B is masking any successful responses with the "valid" error message in order to complete the condition.  But it does what I need, thanks.